# Proving a map in a commutative diagram is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are topological groups, with $H \subset G$. I have the following commutative diagram with $f$ being continuous and $p$ being an open surjection (canonical projection). Does this imply that $h$ is continuous?

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G @>{f}>> G\\
@VpVV @VVpV\\
G/H @>{h}>> G/H
\end{CD}

Take $U$ an open set in $G/H$. I have to show $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $G/H$, i.e. $p^{-1}(h^{-1}(U))$ is opened in G.

I know $p^{-1}(h^{-1}(U))=(h \circ p)^{-1}(U)=(p \circ f)^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(p^{-1}(U))$.
But does this help to prove the claim?

Comment: What are G and H?

Comment: Ah topological groups

Comment: Your question should state what $G$ and $H$ are.

Comment: I edited it, waiting for the approval

Comment: Presumably $G/H$ is endowed with the quotient topology. Then yes, because of the definition of the quotient topology. Alternatively, use the universal property of final topologies, $h$ is continuous iff $h \circ p$ is continuous.

Comment: Actually I didn't realized that if p is the projection map and we endowed $G/H$ with the quotient topology, that $p$ was continuous. But then I am basically done right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map defined on a quotient space $G{/}H$ is continuous iff its composition with the quotient map $p : G \to G{/}H$ is continuous, so $h$ is continuous iff $ h \circ p$ is, and $h \circ p = p \circ f$ by the diagram, and $p$ is continuous by definition, so $h$ is continuous when $f$ is (so we have a composition of continuous maps in $p \circ f$).

Comment: Why in this proof we don't use the fact that the map $p$ is opened?

Comment: @roi_saumon We only need it is quotient. An open surjection is a quotient map.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what the topology is on $G / H$, but the only reasonable topology to use in this situation is the quotient topology, which by definition is the strongest topology such that the projection map $p$ is continuous.

So, since $U \subset G / H$ is open and $p$ is continuous, it follows that $p^{-1}(U) \subset G$ is open.

Next, since $f$ is continuous, it follows that $f^{-1}(p^{-1}(U) \subset G$ is open.

Finally, since from your hypothesis $p$ is an open map, it follows that the set $p(f^{-1}(p^{-1}(U))) = h^{-1}(U) \subset G/H$ is open (that equation between sets uses the hypothesis that $p$ is surjective).

Comment: The last line uses the surjectivity of $p$ as well

Comment: Thanks, I added a remark to that effect.

Comment: It seems weird that we have to use the fact that $p$ is an open map no?

Comment: What's happening here is that every open surjective map is a quotient map. So, what's really being used is that $p$ is a quotient map. You could easily have written your own question without that hypothesis, if it had occured to you to use the more common convention of a "quotient map".